# Switch application view without redirecting the user

Tags: javascript, html, browser, frontend

I want to build a very simple one-page web application that should be able to handle two states - *logging in* (the application should display login window during this phase and handle user's input) and *user interaction* (a chat window should be displayed).

Is there any standard way to build the application so that whenever user requests the webpage, it displays the login window first and only after the user enters their account data, the application reloads all of the resources (js, css, images, etc.), displays the chat UI and lets the user access the core application functionality without having to redirec the user to a different webpage?

Edit: I know how to fetch / send the data from / to the server and display the result to the document. But I am talking complete document rewrite here. Is this possible?

Comment: you may find [jquery](http://jquery.com/) useful

Comment: it is easily achieved with angularjs, for example.  I am sure other frameworks do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this purpose, jquery has an easy to use method for using ajax.
Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp